# Ошибка на телефоне при нажатии кнопки, отсутствие её на эмуляторе

Tags: java, android-sdk

По нажатию кнопки на эмуляторе ничего не происходит, на телефоне через 2сек ошибка вылетает, что не так?

```
 package com.example.start;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      MyTask mt;
      TextView tvInfo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
    }
    public void onclick(View v) {
        mt = new MyTask();
        mt.execute();
      }
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

          protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
              Document doc = null;
              try {
                  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
                  try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/").get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

              tvInfo.setText(doc.title());

            return null;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Измененный код:

```
package com.example.start;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      MyTask mt;
      TextView tvInfo;
      Document doc = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
    }
    public void onclick(View v) {
        mt = new MyTask();
        mt.execute();
      }
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          tvInfo.setText("Begin");
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
          try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          return null;
        }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      String title = doc.title();
      tvInfo.setText(title);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Простите, но уже вызывают раздражение вопросы с просьбой о устранении ошибки, не сопровождающиеся стэктрэйсом оной.

Comment: Простите, но при чем тут синтаксический анализ?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` включен?

Answer (score 1):

В XML для button есть такая строчка?

```
android:onClick="onclick"
```

doc в onPostExecute действительно лучше проверять на null

Кстати не советую юзать Jsoup'овский connect(String url).get(). У самого были с этим проблемы были.
Я использовал стандартный HttpClient, а потом уже полученный документ парсил с помощью Jsoup. Не знаю почему (хотя мысли все-таки есть), но HttpClient при наличии интернета отрабатывал всегда, стандартный же Jsoup connect(String url).get() довольно часто не давал результата.

И на всякий случай Jsoup.jar лежит в проекте в папке lib?

Comment: onClick прописан, jsoup.jar лежит.

Comment: @hetop но все-таки еще раз советую не юзать connect(String url).get()

Comment: спасибо, а можно подробно про httpclient?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410823/how-to-use-defaulthttpclient-in-android

вот тут вроде пример как считать весь документ в строку  по ссылке

потом просто есть метод parse вроде у Jsoup, куда можно передать строку

Так работает у меня чуть медленнее, но во много раз стабильнее

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум, первое же, что бросается в глаза - вы пытаетесь взаимодействовать с view не из UI потока. Перенесите обновление *tvInfo* из *doInBackground* в *onPostExecute*.

И ещё, при вызове *doc.title()* есть большая вероятность получения *NullPointerException*.

Comment: А из за чего может быть NullPointerException? Заключил tvInfo в onPostExecute но ничего не происходит, добавил onPreExecute, при нажатии выдается текст "получение данных" и сколько не ждешь ничего не обрабатывается.

Comment: Если у вас на строчке *doc = Jsoup.connect("http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/").get();* произойдёт исключение, то переменная *doc* останется неинициализированной, следовательно, при попытке вызова doc.title() получим *NullPointerException*.

И покажите код после исправлений, иначе можно долго гадать, в чём проблема.

Comment: Добавил измененный код, буду очень благодарен если поможете ;)

Comment: По-прежнему продолжает падать с ошибкой? Если да, то стэктрэйс в студию. И, в любом случае, вывод logcat'а (разумеется, отфильтрованный по package name) пригодился бы.

Comment: Нет, падать перестал, но и title не грузит. Вывод с logcat щас кину.

Comment: Вывод с logcat
http://goo.gl/ZRgz5